# SAS create multi dataset by array or some easy way

Tags: sas

My data looks like

```
data have;
input genre1 genre2 genre3 genre4 year type$;
datalines;
1 1 1 1 1990 Y
2 2 2 2 1992 N
3 3 3 3 1998 Y
4 4 4 4 1999 Y
;
run;
```

I create four dataset by this code

```
data G1 G2 G3 G4 ; 
set have;
genre = genre1;  if genre1 then output G1; 
genre = genre2;  if genre2 then output G2; 
genre = genre3;  if genre3 then output G3; 
genre = genre4;  if genre4 then output G4; 
run;
```

and create new data set

```
data new;
set G1-G4;
run;
```

But actually I have a lot of genre... This code is so hard. Is there have some convenient method to create multi dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you refine the question? Each outputs G1 to G4 are identical. (Because *if genreX* then  is always true. ) How about you could show how you'd like the end data to look.

Comment: I suggest creating the SAS code using excel formulas and then pasting the formatted SAS code from excel to SAS

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve here.  As @pinegulf states, you're just duplicating the first 4 rows as the row values are identical for each genre.  Is it possible for them to be different?
Generally, splitting data into multiple datasets is not necessary, especially as you are joining them back together again.  Post some more realistic data (if possible) and what you want the final dataset to look like.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Is it that you want a dataset with all the genres? Because going by your question, you want what you have multiplied by the number of genres!

Comment: I think what you want is to transpose the table?

Comment: Is this a homework question? It's the third time this has been posted this week.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the goal is to create a new data set that contains replicates of  `year` and `type` for each `genre`.  Such a new data set would want to remove the original `genre1-genre4`.

The code in the question only seems hard because you are unfamiliar with some SAS concepts.

Here are two ways:

Transposition using `DATA` Step and `array`:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array genres genre1-genre4;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(genres);
    genre = genres(_n_);
    output;
  end;
  keep genre year type;
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by genre year type;
run;
```

Tranposition using `Proc TRANSPOSE`

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_ rename=col1=genre);
  by year type notsorted;
  var genre1-genre4;
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by genre year type;
run;
```

This new data set is a *categorical* form of data and highly suitable in SAS for additional DATA or PROC processing that involves `BY` or `CLASS` statements.  The categorical variable would be `genre`.